How to filter based on the metadata in ChromaDB between two values?
I want to restrict the search during querying time in chromaDB by filtering based on the dates I'm storing in the metadata. I want to only search for documents between 2 dates. I tried the following where condition -

results = collection.query( 
                    query_embeddings=query_embedding,
                    n_results=5, 
                    where={"timestamp": 
                           {"$lte":datetime.strptime('2024-01-10',"%Y-%m-%d").timestamp(),
                            "$gte":datetime.strptime('2024-01-01',"%Y-%m-%d").timestamp()}},
                )

But I am getting this error-

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

I figured out how to construct the where clause -
where = {'$and':[
              {'timestamp': {
                       "$gte": start_timestamp}
              }, 
              {'timestamp': {
                        "$lte": end_timestamp}
              }]
         }

This works.
